# Saving version number to package.json in Gitlab yaml

Tags: github, gitlab, yaml

I am able to successfully get the version number from my package.json and increment it, however I need to save the new version back to package.json and save it.

How can I do this in the below script in Gitlab

```
build_android:
  stage: build
  script:
    - export VERSION_NUMBER=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
    - echo "Current version number:" $VERSION_NUMBER
    - export NEW_VERSION_NUMBER=$(echo "$VERSION_NUMBER + 0.0.1" | bc)
    - echo "New version number:" $NEW_VERSION_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard method of reading/writing/upgrading the version of the package.json is to use `npm version`.

Alternatively, you can use the `npm version` command to update the package.json. The flags such as `major`, `minor` etc can automatically increase the semantic version. The `patch` flag can create tags and commits automatically.

```
build_android:
  stage: build
  script:
    - export VERSION_NUMBER=$(node -p "require('./package.json').version")
    - echo "Current version number:" $VERSION_NUMBER
    - export NEW_VERSION_NUMBER=$(echo "$VERSION_NUMBER + 0.0.1" | bc)
    - echo "New version number:" $NEW_VERSION_NUMBER
    - npm version $NEW_VERSION_NUMBER
```